# openSUSE on Virtual Box : Guest Additions

Tags: virtualbox, opensuse

I am using openSUSE 11.0 guest in Ubuntu 9.10 host on Virtual Box. When I try to install [Guest-Additions](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2009/11/25/how-to-install-virtualbox-guest-additions-in-linux-ubuntu-debian-fedora-opensuse-red-hat-and-more/) it doesn't really work as expected, the screen is not sized to fit the correct resolution, seamless working between 2 OS doesn't happen !

Has anyone tried installing Guest-Additions in openSUSE ?

**UPDATE** : Tried the Guest-Additions after fully updating openSUSE 11.0, it still doesn't works

**UPDATE** : Tried with OpenSUSE 11.2, it gets stuck in Virtual Box. In general OpenSUSE doesn't work with Virtual Box.

Comment: I would try the newest stable openSUSE & VirtualBox first. But yes, I have gotten it to work on a Windows host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it say successfully installed and so?
(Maybe you should go with VMWare Player.. know this is a workaround, sorry.)

Comment: @Shiki : Yes it does, but then it behaves somewhat strangely. Will give it a try on VMWare (though I hate working with vmx images).

Comment: @Arkapravo: strange == normal I guess. :) VirtualBox had some strange problem here also. Some people say VMWare , some says Parallels. Beats me which one would be better. I prefer VMWare (Workstation 7.1).

Comment: @Shiki : If it is so, then may be if I can over come this vmx hatred, I will try to use OpenSUSE on VMWare Player !

Comment: @Shiki : Are there OpenSUSE 11.2 VMWare images available ? ..... do you have any links ?

Comment: @Arkapravo: Get the CD, install it like you would on a physical machine. Maybe you can get images but those are for try out not for permanent installation. Try this: http://www.thoughtpolice.co.uk/vmware/ or http://www.easyvmx.com/ (but in the latest Player, you can create vmx for yourself.)

Comment: Why would yo do that? Just boot it up... I don't see a point in that, sorry

Comment: @Shiki : OKay !

Comment: @Arkapravo - Hope you're not mad or anything. If you boot the .ISO up, you  are at the exact same point. That's why.

Comment: @Shiki : I do not know how the new VMWare functions. Further, I haven't been able to find out how can I create vmx images in the new player, hence my question can iso be converted to vmx ? 

In Virtual Box, one can use the iso without the 'BOOTING UP' process. All I wanted to know if there is any interface in VMWare which converts iso to vmx ? That would make things easier for me, than a lengthy download.